# Why is this working? (generating values in main thread and consuming them in some other background thread in Android)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin

As far as I know, threads copy variables in their local cache.
What I'm doing is, I'm getting values in the main thread and then I'm consuming them in some other background (renderer) thread. Like this-

```
class MySurfaceView ... {
    private var someValue = 0

    // Called from the main thread
    fun updateValue() {
        someValue++
    }
    
    fun render() {
        Thread {
            // Here someValue variable is consumed
            // and it's always up to date.
            ....
        }.start()
    }
}
```

So, inside the runnable passed to the thread started inside render(), 'someValue' is always up to date and I didn't even mark it volatile. If threads copy variables to their local cache then why is it happening? Is it because an implicit reference of the outer class is being kept and the value is coming from there (if this is true, then in cases like this, where I have one generator and multiple consumer threads, would it always be safe to not mark the field which is updated only by the generator thread as volatile? As read/write operations on volatile is costly)?
The same thing also happens when I start a coroutine and try access 'someValue' inside it.

Comment: "As far as I know, threads copy variables in their local cache" -- no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> threads copy variables in their local cache.

This is not true, which explains your findings. Basically, you confused the *liberties* an implementation may exercise with *guarantees* the specification provides. The Java Memory Model (which Kotlin follows as well) simply gives the implementation the freedom to do whatever it likes with state that doesn't get shared through synchronizing actions. It may store it on the stack or in a register, and it may also work with the original on the heap.

One especially relevant detail is that `println()` is a `synchronized` method, so if in your actual code you had `println`s in both threads to see what's going on, you introduced synchronization that made the results come out right.

On the other hand, it's quite easy to see a program that takes this freedom, for example

```
Thread 1:

var runningFlag = true

while (runningFlag) {}

Thread 2:

sleep(1000)
runningFlag = false
```

Thread 1 is quite likely to go on executing forever, or even to be compiled similar to `currentThread().join()` -- doing no actual work, but never completing.

Comment: I'm still confused. I get that variables are not always copied to a local cache. But, not using volatile or introducing synchronization in a situation like the example in my question is safe or not?

Comment: It isn't safe. The variable must be volatile to ensure that another thread observes updates to it. This is what my snippet is intended to show.